# Create hyperlink in Telegram message sent by bot via script / google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, telegram, telegram-bot

My current script is:

```
function EnviarTelegram(botSecret, chatId, body) {
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + botSecret + "/sendMessage?text=" + encodeURIComponent(body) + "&chat_id=" + chatId + "&parse_mode=HTML");
}
```

The formula in Google Sheets I use to send the message is:

```
=EnviarTelegram("Code to Bot","Code to ChatId","Created Message")
```

I would like to be able to create the following message:

```
"Full list of games tomorrow

Click here to access"
```

In `Click here to access` I wish there was a hyperlink for example: `www.google.com/testtesttesttest`

Is there any way to be able to adjust the script or the text created for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query parameter, `parse_mode=HTML` is used. So I thought that in this case, HTML tags can be used for `text`. When you want to use `=EnviarTelegram("Code to Bot","Code to ChatId","Created Message")`, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
=EnviarTelegram("Code to Bot","Code to ChatId","Created Message")
```

#### To:

```
=EnviarTelegram("Code to Bot","Code to ChatId","Full list of games tomorrow\n\n<a href='https://www.google.com/testtesttesttest'>Click here to access</a>")
```

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, the follow error ```"Exception: Request failed for https://api.telegram.org returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can't parse entities: Unsupported start tag \"br\" at byte offset 27"}"```

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your error message, in that case, how about modifying from `Full list of games tomorrow<br><br><a href='https://www.google.com/testtesttesttest'>Click here to access</a>` to `Full list of games tomorrow\n\n<a href='https://www.google.com/testtesttesttest'>Click here to access</a>`? Or `Full list of games tomorrow%0A%0A<a href='https://www.google.com/testtesttesttest'>Click here to access</a>`?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike This is perfect mate, one edit to space lines: ```/n/n``` to double click in ```ALT+ENTER```

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your replying, I updated my answer.